# HttpServletResponse getOutputStream sending html code on csv file

Tags: java, spring, weblogic

I'm trying to download a csv file but html code (header and footer) is also sent into the file. I'm using weblogic, but with tomcat works fine. The code is below:

```
public void downloadCSVReport(String csvFile, HttpServletResponse response){
        try {

            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=example.csv"); 
            response.setContentType("text/csv");

            ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(csvFile.toString().getBytes(REPORT_ENCODING));
            IOUtils.copy(bais, response.getOutputStream());

            response.flushBuffer();

        } catch( IOException e ){
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This code in my Spring webapp works

```
public static void putFileInResponse(HttpServletResponse response, File file, String contentType) throws IOException {
    // Set the headers
    response.setContentType(contentType);// "application/octet-stream" for example
    response.setContentLength((int) file.length());
    response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", new StringBuilder("attachment; filename=\"").append(file.getName()).append("\"").toString());
    response.addHeader("Content-Description", "File Transfer");
    response.addHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
    response.addHeader("Expires", "0");
    response.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, must-revalidate");
    response.addHeader("Pragma", "public");
    response.addHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");

    // Write the content of the file in the response
    try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file); OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream()) {
        IOUtils.copyLarge(fis, os);
        os.flush();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting the ContentLength worked! Doesnt matter anymore the extra data, because of the ContentLength now is csvFile.length(). Thanks!!